# !doctype html - ломает весь сайт. Почему?

Tags: css, html5

Внёс на сайт код: `<!doctype html>`
Повело весь дизайн по тегу `line-height`. Ведь это относится к HTML5, он должен более грамотно интерпретировать теги.
А здесь наоборот.
Т.е. как меня учили, тег описанный в элементе более приоритетнее, чем тег описанный ранее в стилях (если не применяются аргументы в стиле `!important` ). Ведь так и работают интерпретируемые языки программирования.
Но что здесь происходит?

За что минусуют? Непонятно.

---

Был ранее `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
И с ним всё интерпретируется так как надо.

---

Пока решение не найдено - вернул `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
Всё отлично работает. Но FireFox по листингу показывает, дескать это ошибка. Вот почему и принялся исправлять этот тег.
HTML 4.1 - ещё пока морально не сильно устарел.

Comment: !DOCTYPE должен быть написан заглавными буквами - возможно, в этом проблема. А вообще код покажите - так только гадать можно, что у Вас там сломалось.

Comment: в HTML5 регистр тэгов не важен - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE

Comment: Нужен код. Без него ничего не сказать. Может браузер стал «более правильно интерпретировать» и ваши ошибки стало лучше видно

Comment: @mymedia, ну я потому и написано "возможно". Скорее всего, дело вообще не в doctype, но без кода понять проблему нельзя

Comment: А что было до `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: @klifort до него код работал так как нужно. Убирал пространство между строк на модуле онлайн телевидения.

Comment: Браузер Лиса построен иначе. Если бы бы браузеры воспринимали всё одинаково, то не было Бы необходимости в кроссбраузерной вёрстке.

Comment: @I_CaR, возможно поможет  разобратся в проблеме - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268563/doctype-affects-rendering-of-line-height

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

или

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Моё мнение проработать line-height, раз такое дело.
Ссылку в комментариях оставь на свой сайт.

Comment: Вы так пишите "или" как-будто этот код означает одно и тоже....

Comment: @by Verng отличия есть, но и варианты решения есть под разные. Добрый день.

Comment: «Ссылку в комментариях оставь на свой сайт» — такие вещи на Stack Overflow не допускаются, из вопросов и ответов должна получаться самодостаточная база знаний без сторонних ссылок